# C# Devcomponents could not found

Tags: c#, dotnetbar

I try to run one C# project in visual studio 2013 but it have 2 errors about DevComponenets.

```
this.line1 = new DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.Line();
```

and

```
private DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.Line line1;
```

For this two line i have this error : The type or namespace name DevComponenets could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Can anyone tell me what i should to do please ?

Comment: Add a using directive, or a reference to the assembly?

Comment: you should have dotnetbar installed on your dev machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In the solution explorer on the right, right-click "References" and select "Add Reference"
2) From there, click on the "Browse" tab, and find the .dll "DevComponents.DotNetBar2.dll", and add that to your form